# Problem using PCL 1.8 with ROS Indigo

Tags: pcl, pcl-1.7, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to compile a package based on the lccp_segmentation algorithm available in the pcl-trunk. The compilation and installation of the pcl-trunk were fine since I have the same version of the package in a simple .cpp file (not in ROS), and I can compile everything with no problems. But when I try to compile my ROS package it seems to be a conflict between PCL 1.7 and 1.8, since the output in the terminal is something like:

```
link library [libpcl_common.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:  /usr/local/lib
```

Which I guess it yields to the following error:

```
*** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so', needed by `/home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/devel/lib/segmentation_lccp/segmentationLCCP'
```

My setup is:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Ros indigo
- PCL (1.7 and 1.8 are both installed)

I have just a very basic knowledge about the linking stuff and cmake, I also surfed a lot in the internet but none had my same problem. I hope to have gave you enough information, below there are the outputs of the catkin_make and cmake commands of the above commented source codes.

Thanks in advance,

Here the output of the catkin_make command:

```
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps segmentation_lccp
Base path: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis
Source space: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/src
Build space: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/build
Devel space: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/devel
Install space: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/install
Whitelisted packages: segmentation_lccp
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Using CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES: segmentation_lccp
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - segmentation_lccp
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'segmentation_lccp'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(grasping_novel_objects/segmentation_lccp)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   serialization
-- checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   package 'libopenni2' not found
-- Could NOT find OpenNI2 (missing:  OPENNI2_LIBRARY OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** io features related to openni2 will be disabled
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing:  ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing:  DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing:  _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to libusb-1.0 will be disabled
-- checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   package 'libopenni2' not found
-- Could NOT find OpenNI2 (missing:  OPENNI2_LIBRARY OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to openni2 will be disabled
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing:  ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing:  DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing:  _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to dssdk will be disabled
-- Could NOT find RSSDK (missing:  _RSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to rssdk will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- looking for PCL_STEREO
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- looking for PCL_TRACKING
-- looking for PCL_2D
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- looking for PCL_SURFACE
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- looking for PCL_ML
-- looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
-- looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
-- looking for PCL_RECOGNITION
-- looking for PCL_PEOPLE
-- looking for PCL_OUTOFCORE
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- segmentation_lccp: 2 messages, 1 services
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning at grasping_novel_objects/segmentation_lccp/CMakeLists.txt:123 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target segmentationLCCP
  because files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    link library [libpcl_common.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_octree.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_io.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_kdtree.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_search.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_sample_consensus.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_filters.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_tracking.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_features.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_surface.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_segmentation.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_visualization.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_registration.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_keypoints.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_recognition.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_people.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib
    link library [libpcl_outofcore.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:
      /usr/local/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/build"
####
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _segmentation_lccp_generate_messages_check_deps_filtered_object
[  0%] [  0%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target _segmentation_lccp_generate_messages_check_deps_segmentationLCCP
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so', needed by `/home/nicola/ros_ws/master_thesis/devel/lib/segmentation_lccp/segmentationLCCP'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [grasping_novel_objects/segmentation_lccp/CMakeFiles/segmentationLCCP.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  0%] Built target _segmentation_lccp_generate_messages_check_deps_Objects
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

The CMakeLists.txt is:

```
      cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
      project(segmentation_lccp)

      find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      roscpp
      rospy
      std_msgs
      tf
      sensor_msgs
      message_generation
      message_runtime
      visualization_msgs
    )
    
    find_package(  PCL 1.8 REQUIRED  )
    find_package(  OpenCV REQUIRED  )
    
    ## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
    set(Boost_REALPATH  ON)
    find_package(Boost 1.54 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
    if(Boost_FOUND)
      include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    endif()

    add_message_files(                                    
   FILES
   filtered_object.msg
   Objects.msg                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   )
  ## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
   sensor_msgs
   visualization_msgs
 )
 catkin_package(  
 #  INCLUDE_DIRS include
 #  LIBRARIES LCCP_segmentation
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp tf rospy std_msgs message_runtime message_generation sensor_msgs 
 #  DEPENDS system_lib
 )
 include_directories(
 ./include
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 )

 link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
 add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

 add_executable(segmentationLCCP src/segmentationLCCP.cpp  src/DetectObjectsOnTable.cpp src/LCCP.cpp src/Segmentation.cpp src/smooth_pcl_mls.cpp src/fill_occluded_sides.cpp)
add_dependencies(segmentationLCCP LCCP_segmentation_generate_messages_cpp)
target_link_libraries(segmentationLCCP
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

I report here also the output of cmake command of the other executable which is not based on ROS and which works fine:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- checking for module 'eigen3'
--   found eigen3, version 3.2.0
-- Found eigen: /usr/include/eigen3  
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   serialization
-- checking for module 'libopenni'
--   found libopenni, version 1.5.4.0
-- Found openni: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so  
-- checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   package 'libopenni2' not found
-- Could NOT find OpenNI2 (missing:  OPENNI2_LIBRARY OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** io features related to openni2 will be disabled
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing:  ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing:  DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing:  _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
-- Found libusb-1.0: /usr/include  
** WARNING ** io features related to libusb-1.0 will be disabled
-- checking for module 'flann'
--   found flann, version 1.8.4
-- Found Flann: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a  
-- Found qhull: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so  
-- checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   package 'libopenni2' not found
-- Could NOT find OpenNI2 (missing:  OPENNI2_LIBRARY OPENNI2_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to openni2 will be disabled
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing:  ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing:  DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing:  _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to dssdk will be disabled
-- Could NOT find RSSDK (missing:  _RSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to rssdk will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- Found PCL_COMMON: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.so  
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- Found PCL_OCTREE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_octree.so  
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- Found PCL_IO: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so  
-- looking for PCL_STEREO
-- Found PCL_STEREO: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_stereo.so  
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- Found PCL_KDTREE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so  
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- Found PCL_SEARCH: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.so  
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- Found PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so  
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- Found PCL_FILTERS: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_filters.so  
-- looking for PCL_TRACKING
-- Found PCL_TRACKING: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_tracking.so  
-- looking for PCL_2D
-- Found PCL_2D: /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8  
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- Found PCL_FEATURES: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_features.so  
-- looking for PCL_SURFACE
-- Found PCL_SURFACE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_surface.so  
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- Found PCL_GEOMETRY: /usr/local/include/pcl-1.8  
-- looking for PCL_ML
-- Found PCL_ML: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_ml.so  
-- looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
-- Found PCL_SEGMENTATION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so  
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- Found PCL_VISUALIZATION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_visualization.so  
-- looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
-- Found PCL_REGISTRATION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_registration.so  
-- looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
-- Found PCL_KEYPOINTS: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so  
-- looking for PCL_RECOGNITION
-- Found PCL_RECOGNITION: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_recognition.so  
-- looking for PCL_PEOPLE
-- Found PCL_PEOPLE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_people.so  
-- looking for PCL_OUTOFCORE
-- Found PCL_OUTOFCORE: /usr/local/lib/libpcl_outofcore.so  
-- Found PCL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_octree.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_octree.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;vtkCommon;vtkFiltering;vtkImaging;vtkGraphics;vtkGenericFiltering;vtkIO;vtkRendering;vtkVolumeRendering;vtkHybrid;vtkWidgets;vtkParallel;vtkInfovis;vtkGeovis;vtkViews;vtkCharts;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_stereo.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_stereo.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_filters.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_filters.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_tracking.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_tracking.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_features.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_features.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_surface.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_surface.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_ml.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_ml.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_visualization.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_visualization.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_registration.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_registration.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_recognition.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_recognition.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_people.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_people.so;optimized;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_outofcore.so;debug;/usr/local/lib/libpcl_outofcore.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqhull.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp_s.a;vtkCommon;vtkFiltering;vtkImaging;vtkGraphics;vtkGenericFiltering;vtkIO;vtkRendering;vtkVolumeRendering;vtkHybrid;vtkWidgets;vtkParallel;vtkInfovis;vtkGeovis;vtkViews;vtkCharts (Required is at least version "1.8") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nicola/Codes/LCCP_segmentation/lccp-segmentation/build
nicola@nicola-Aspire-E5-571:~/Codes/LCCP_segmentation/lccp-segmentation/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target LCCP
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LCCP.dir/src/LCCP.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LCCP.dir/src/DetectObjectsOnTable.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LCCP.dir/src/Segmentation.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/LCCP
[ 50%] Built target LCCP
Scanning dependencies of target example_lccp_segmentation
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example_lccp_segmentation.dir/src/example_lccp_segmentation.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example_lccp_segmentation.dir/src/removeTable.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/example_lccp_segmentation
[ 83%] Built target example_lccp_segmentation
Scanning dependencies of target example_lccp_segmentation_new
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example_lccp_segmentation_new.dir/src/example_lccp_segmentation_new.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/example_lccp_segmentation_new
[100%] Built target example_lccp_segmentation_new
```

The CMakeLists.txt of this one is the same of the one reported concerning the PCL stuff.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226460/problem-using-pcl-1.8-with-ros-indigo/) by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) on 2017-09-30**:
I'm getting the same problem, except I compiled pcl 1.8 from source and `make install`'d it. I tried uninstalling pcl 1.7 completely `sudo apt-get uninstall libpcl-1.7-all` and `sudo apt-get uninstall libpcl-1.7-all-dev` but then I get errors because I have no pcl_ros nor pcl_conversions...

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2017-10-01**:
I managed to make it work with both 1.7 and 1.8 libraries installed. However I guess that you can simply installed that ros packages you deleted and that's all:   sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl*

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2017-10-01**:
If it may helps [here](If it may helps [here](https://github.com/NicolaCovallero/tos_supervoxels) there is a simple C++ library based on PCL 1.8 and [here](https://github.com/NicolaCovallero/iri_tos_supervoxels) the ROS pkg that uses it.

**Comment by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) on 2017-10-08**:
got it to work by switching the order I call dependencies in my CMakelists.txt, basically I had to look at pcl BEFORE pcl_ros, that way it found the correct pcl 1.8 libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just resolved it by removing the Cmake Cache, then it compiled correctly.

Although I still don't understand why it was not working fine the first time.

---

Originally posted by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) with karma: 113 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on 2016-07-08**:
I need to do something similar. I followed some of your lead about how to set up the `CMakeLists.txt`. But I end up with lots of warnings like `CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:149 (add_executable): Cannot generate a safe linker search path for target <snip>`

**Comment by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on 2016-07-08**:
And lots of repetitions similar to `link library [libpcl_common.so] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in: /usr/local/lib`

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2016-07-08**:
Did you remove everything in the "build" folder of the workspace and then recompiled all the packages you have? That is what I did, I m sorry but I have just a very basic knowledge of cmake and I actually do not know why deleting the cache and recompiling everything works, but it works.

**Comment by [Caba](https://answers.ros.org/users/23081/caba/) on 2016-07-08**:
Otherwise create a new workspace and try compiling there your package, I am pretty sure it is not problem of the CMakeLists.txt file. More than this I cannot help, sorry.